# How can we control/restrict the Users after integration of BBB with Moodle server?

Tags: moodle, bigbluebutton

I have installed Bigbluebutton 0.81 on one server and installed Moodle on other server,and integrated BBB on Moodle server using Server salt id & URL, it is working fine, now i want to create User registration on Moodle server and give BBB Live session access through the Moodle server. Here Moodle & BBB servers are both independent and both have different ip's, after integration of Moodle - BBB how can we control users, because once they enter into BBB server then anybody can see( even non  registered users also ) the URL/Address bar of the session in web browser, is there any alternate solution to control the user in Moodle server / BBB Server.

Already i have tried with iFrame option, but still i can see BBB server URL using View source option, even if we restrict right click also we can see by using ctl +U key,also i have tried another methode by POP up Window, but it is also displaying Address bar.

So how can we restrict/Hide URL or Control the Non- registered user?

Answer (score 1):

How have you integrated BBB?

There is a Moodle plugin for BBB - https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=mod_bigbluebuttonbn

and a discussion with the developer on the Moodle forum - https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=185675